# Math on batch (win)

Tags: math, windows-7, batch-file, cmd, formula

I am developing a CMD batch.  I want to do some math in it. This formula: `(x+1)100:y`

So in batch, `x = %x%, and y = %y%`. I know how to set the variables. Now, how can batch calculate this? (WINDOWS CMD)

Do I need something extra?

(I need this to be available to users of Windows XP to 7.)

Comment: You want to work out a percentage, given two batch file variables, 'x' and 'y'?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The set command supports some limited calculation.  In your case, you want:
`set /a result=(100*x)/y`

Run `set /?` to see full documentation on what is supported.  The `/a` switch does automatic variable substitution, so you can use `x` instead of `%x%`.

Answer (score 15):

```
@echo off

set x=42
set y=5

set /a z = 100 * x / y

echo %z%
```

The `set /a` command allows you to assign the result of a mathematical expression to a variable (at that, the `%`'s around variable names in these expressions aren't required). See `set /?` for the list of supported operators and details.

Note that Windows batch files don't support floating-point arithmetic, so if an expression result is a fractional number, only the integer part will be counted. For example, *3/2* evaluates as *1* and *2/3* as *0*.

Answer (score 3):

DON'T do maths in batch. If you are doing percentage, you might have decimals and batch doesn't support decimals.(floating). Use vbscript or something better.

save the below as caculate.vbs

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
x = objArgs(0)
y = objArgs(1)
WScript.Echo ( x + 1 ) * 100  / y
```

and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo calculate.vbs 4 5
```

Comment: and btw; i forgot that it wasn't x+1 but y+1. So like (x * 100) / ( y + 1 )

Answer (score 2):

- `set /a` (any arithmatic)
- `set /a 2+2` adding
- `set /a 2-2`  subtracting
- `set /a 2*2` multiplying
- `set /a 2/2` deviding
- `set /a 2^2` exponet

use brackets and parentheses to show the properties of the equations
for ex. `2(2+2)=8` Shows distributive property.

Comment: These examples need quotes `set /a "2^2"` needs quotes (without quotes it's just 22) and `^` is logical XOR. The last one is an error because it's missing an operator: `2*(2+2)`=`8`

Comment: `^` is XOR not exponent